# Set time zone of hh:mm picker with moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timezone, momentjs

I am trying to configure an hour:minute time picker. I am using the awesome [MTR Datepicker from Gihub](http://mtrdesign.github.io/mtr-datepicker/docs.html) which is working except I can't change the time zone.

What I need is a user to select his time zone from a drop down list, e.g. 'Europe/London'. Then the script grabs the offset value of the time zone (+60minutes or 3600seconds).

Using that time zone offset I want to display the selectable minutes in 15m increments that are for the future.

So if the users time was 01:14 pm I want times 01:15< to be selectable.

**Problem**

If I open the script in a browser the MTR Datepicker library by default is set to **my** local time (+02:00 GMT) by default.

So if GMT is 12:00 AM and my local time is 02:00PM I get times from 02:15 < until 11:45.

But I want to be able to select a new time zone, say Europe/London (+01:00 GMT) and be shown times from 01:15... you get my gist.

I don't know how to override that behaviour.

Here is the library (1856 lines): [MTR Datepicker.js Gitub](https://github.com/mtrdesign/mtr-datepicker/blob/master/scripts/mtr-datepicker.js)

Something in there is detecting my computers local time zone and I want to override that with the users selected time zone.

Here is the configuration code on my page... as you can see I am passing in the unix timestamp (valueOf()) into the timestamp configuration option but the library is detecting and using my local time by default.

```
<script>
    var m = moment().utcOffset(); // new time now
    var config = {
        target: 'timePicker',
        timestamp: m.valueOf(),
        future: true,
        minutes: {
            min: 0,
            max: 45,
            step: 15,
        },
    };
    var myDatepicker = new MtrDatepicker(config);

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#resultTime").html(myDatepicker.format('H:mm A'));
    });

    myDatepicker.onChange('time', function() {
        $("#resultTime").html(myDatepicker.format('H:mm A'));
    });
</script>
```

How do I change the displayed hours and minutes based on the time zone offset instead of a users local time?

Comment: If someone needs here is a jsfiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/eq0k5ovr/

Comment: Yes, thank you! I tried for ages to get the fiddle working.

Comment: If you pass the *future: true* parameter, the datepicker will always stop you to select dates/time in the past. Maybe this is causing your problem, so try to change it to *false*. Anyway, it will be good if the datepicker supports time zones, so if you still have any issues I'll consider to implement feature like this.

Comment: Hey valkirilov, very honoured and impressed that you responded to this question! I really love this date picker and time zones would be awesome. If there could be a configuration option where you set it to an offset of GMT that would be useful. So if I am in Paris, I set the config option to an offset of 120 minutes and I get my time zone.

Comment: Some background: I am getting my time zone offset from the DateTime object in PHP and I need to hard set the date picker to a specific time zone that a user selects.

Comment: You would need to integrate [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).  Have you tried yet?

Comment: No I have not, thanks for suggesting that, however it's unclear to me how I would integrate it with the time picker as there is no timezone API inbuilt.

Comment: At the moment I am doing a workaround with moment.js where I am simply getting the hours and minutes as a value and am appending them to a separate drawstring, it's working except for a but where if I click on the time and then click off the time the pm switches to am... I will update my code tomorrow.

Comment: I think I have found a bug with the library, when you click on the hour picker and then click back to the page the time defaults to AM, so if I have chosen 8PM then I click on the time and click away it swings back to AM while the checkbox is still on PM.

Answer (score 0):

The time zones support has been implemented and recently we pushed some bugs fixes and improvements.
For more information how to use them and integrate the plugin with your setup you can rely on the [docs](http://mtrdesign.github.io/mtr-datepicker/docs.html#plugins-timezones).